# Doctrine2 - No foreign key inserted in the table with relation OneToMany(

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with doctrine2 with a simple relationship between the two models
Below I have prepared a simple example

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="PlayerRepository") @Table(name="players")
 */
class Player {
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Wallet", mappedBy="player", cascade={"persist"})
 * @var Wallet[]
 */
private  $wallets;

public function __construct() {
    $this->wallets = new ArrayCollection();
}
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getWallets() {
    return $this->wallets;
}
public function addWallets($wallets) {
    $this->wallets[] = $wallets;
}
}
```

And second class

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="WalletRepository") @Table(name="wallets")
 */

class Wallet
{
/**
* @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
*/
protected $id;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Player", inversedBy="wallets")
 */
private $player;
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}
public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}
public function getPlayer() {
    return $this->player;
}
public function setPlayer($player) {
    $this->player = $player;
}
}
```

For the following code execution, I am not able to add Player object relations to Wallet:

```
player = new Player();
$player->addWallets(new Wallet);
$player->addWallets(new Wallet);
$entityManager->persist($player);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Maybe it will be better seen in the attached picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you have to set this on the [owning site](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html), in this case `Wallet`, give it a try:

```
$player = new Player();

$wallet = new Wallet();
$wallet->setPlayer($player);

$entityManager->persist($player);
$entityManager->persist($wallet);

$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: OK works, but a want assingn many wallets to one player, through Player method addWallets, and Relationships are bidirectional, aren't

Comment: I think that won't work, as written in the article I linked in my answer: _The owning side of a bidirectional association is the side Doctrine "looks at" when determining the state of the association, and consequently whether there is anything to do to update the association in the database._